# Can I accept paypal payment only after number of buyers?

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I want to be able to create minimum buyers deals on my site:

For example, a deal is done only after 100 people have agreed to purchase the product.

My question is, how can I charge their paypal / credit card only after the minimum number of people have joined the deal?

Answer (score 0):

You could charge it anyway and then issue refunds if not enough people sign up. That's what Kickstarter does via Amazon Payments. Of course, you'll need to check with your payment processor to make sure this is within their terms of use.